# Copy just the value to new sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I'm so close on this, but keep getting errors if I try to use .Value or .PasteSpecial xlPasteValue. I'm not sure where to put it, but I've tried multiple options.  I want this to work as is, but just bring over the value, not the formatting.

```
Sub CopyQuoteValues()
    Dim wsOpt As Worksheet, wsQuote As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    Set wsOpt = Worksheets("Software Options")
    Set wsQuote = Worksheets("Quote")
    
    Set rngDest = wsQuote.Range("C4")
    
    
    If wsOpt.Range("G1") = "Cloud" Then
        For Each c In wsOpt.Range("C17", wsOpt.Cells(wsOpt.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Len(c.Offset(0, 7)) > 1 Then 'value in C and I ?
                c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest      'copy ColB
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)  'next paste location
            End If
        Next c
    Else
        For Each c In wsOpt.Range("C17", wsOpt.Cells(wsOpt.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Len(c.Offset(0, 1)) > 0 Then 'value in C and D ?
                c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest      'copy ColB
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next paste location
            End If
        Next c

    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The offset for column `I` is `6` (for column `J` is `7`): `If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Len(c.Offset(0, 6).Value) > 1 Then`. And replace both occurrences of `c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest` with `rngDest.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

### A Simplification

- The following code refers to the `ActiveWorkbook`. If the code is located in the workbook containing these worksheets, you should most definitely use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...)`.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyQuoteValues()

    Dim wsOpt As Worksheet, wsQuote As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rngDest As Range
    Dim secOffset As Long ' Second Check Column Offset
    Dim secVal As Long ' Second Check Value ' = 0 by default
    
    Set wsOpt = Worksheets("Software Options")
    Set wsQuote = Worksheets("Quote")
    Set rngDest = wsQuote.Range("C4")
    
    secOffset = 1
    If wsOpt.Range("G1").Value = "Cloud" Then
        secOffset = 6
        secVal = 1
    End If
    
    For Each c In wsOpt.Range("C17", wsOpt.Cells(wsOpt.Rows.Count, "C") _
            .End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Len(c.Offset(0, secOffset).Value) > secVal Then
            rngDest.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope** this will help you.

instead of using directly `.Copy to Destination` method

```
c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest
```

You can use either:

**Copy only the value**  using `c.Offset(0, -1).Value`

> ```
> rngDest.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
> ' c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest      'copy ColB
> ```

or

**Paste only the value**  using `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

> ```
> c.Offset(0, -1).Copy
> rngDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
> ' c.Offset(0, -1).Copy rngDest      'copy ColB
> ```